# Trouble getting the callout to appear on an MKAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, macos, mapkit

I'm working on a Mac OSX application, and I'm having trouble with the callout appearing next to a pin when a pin is clicked on. I do use the MKMapViewDelegate, and override the following method like so:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[LocationPin class]]) {
    LocationPin *returnPin = [LocationPin createLocationPinForMapView:self.mapOfPins annotation:annotation];
    NSButton *rightButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 80.0)];
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Info"];
    [rightButton setBezelStyle:NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle];
    returnPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    returnPin.canShowCallout = true;
    returnPin.annotation = annotation;
    return returnPin;

}
```

My pins are appearing on the map just fine, but the callouts just are not appearing. I know a common problem people have is they forget to set the title, but my pins definitely have titles, as I can NSLog them. I also tried to override the :

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

method, but it's not getting called when I click on a pin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why aren't you using `dequeueReusableAnnotationWithIdentifier:` method?
This uses less memory as it reuses the same `MKAnnotationView` instance instead of allocating a new one each time this method is called. I assume `LocationPin` is a `MKAnnotationView` subclass. Also, I think your problem comes from creating an annotation view for another map :`self.mapOfPins` instead of calling it for the `mapView` object sent to the delegate.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[LocationPin class]]) {
        static NSString *identifier = @"YourPinIdentifier";
        LocationPin *returnPin = (LocationPin *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (!returnPin){
            returnPin = [LocationPin createLocationPinForMapView:mapView annotation:annotation];
        }
        NSButton *rightButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 80.0)];
        [rightButton setTitle:@"Info"];
        [rightButton setBezelStyle:NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle];
        returnPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        returnPin.canShowCallout = true;
        returnPin.annotation = annotation;
        return returnPin;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I changed my code to use the mapView object sent to the delegate, and I'm still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Have you set the delegate? something like this `self.mapView.delegate = self;` and implement the delegate in the header file `<MKMapViewDelegate>`?

Comment: Yep. In my `viewDidLoad`, have `self.mapOfPins.delegate = self;`, and I implemented the delegate in the header file.

Comment: Could you show the entire `MKMapViewDelegate` methods and also your `viewDidLoad`? Maybe your problem is not in this method.

Comment: Sure. The only other MKMapViewDelegate method I used was `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` and all I have in it is a `NSLog` statement to see if it ever get executed. I also realized that I was setting all these things for my `returnPin`, but I never added it to the mapView. I fixed that, but I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: As for my `viewDidLoad`, I just have a few things to initialize the application : `[super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapOfPins.delegate = self;
    self.mapOfPins.showsUserLocation = true;
    self.mapOfPins.showsCompass = false;
    self.mapOfPins.showsZoomControls = false;
    //Sets up the map view to zoom into the users location
    [self zoomToUser:self.mapOfPins];
    
    //Set up buttons
    self.addPinButton.title = @"Pins";
    [self.mapOfPins addSubview:self.addPinButton];
    [self.mapOfPins addSubview:self.zoomButton];`